# Retrieving data from wrong database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have two SQLiteDatabases in my application. One retrieves the user's input from the class DataEntryHome. The other retrieves the user's input from the class GarmentEntry. I also have two activities which display the user's inputs in the form of a ListView. These are shown in the activities RecapPage and RecapOrderDetails.

To make things simpler for myself as a new java programmer, I have used separate dbHelper, DataProvider and ListDataAdapter classes for the separate databases.

My issue is that in the RecapOrderDetails class, the ListView is populated with the contents from DataEntryHome rather than from GarmentEntry. The ListView in RecapPage works as it should.

Here is all of the code that I think is relevant:

DataEntryHome:

```
public class DataEntryHome extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{

private static Button DataEntryButtonN, SaveDataButton, PreviewButton;
Context context = this;
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
EditText ContactName,ContactSurname,ContactEmail,ContactPhone,ContactAddInfo;
Button saveDetails;
public static ArrayList<String> CUSTOMERS = new ArrayList<String>();
String customers[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    final EditText surnameArray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerSurnameEntry);

    saveDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveDetailsButton);
    saveDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String erm=surnameArray.getText().toString().trim();
            if(erm.length() != 0){
                CUSTOMERS.add(erm);
                surnameArray.setText("");
            }
            Intent arrayItems = new Intent(DataEntryHome.this, RecapPage.class);
            Bundle arrayItemsBundle = new Bundle();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_entry_home);

    ContactName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerFirstNameEntry);
    ContactName.addTextChangedListener(this);
    ContactSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerSurnameEntry);
    ContactSurname.addTextChangedListener(this);
    ContactEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerEmail);
    ContactEmail.addTextChangedListener(this);
    ContactPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerNumber);
    ContactPhone.addTextChangedListener(this);
    ContactAddInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addInfo1);

    setupSaveDataButton();


}

public void addContact(View view) {

    String name = ContactName.getText().toString();
    String surname = ContactSurname.getText().toString();
    String email = ContactEmail.getText().toString();
    String phone = ContactPhone.getText().toString();
    String add_info = ContactAddInfo.getText().toString();

    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    userDbHelper.addInformation(name,surname,email,phone,add_info,sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    userDbHelper.close();
}
```

RecapPage:

```
public class RecapPage extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView listView;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
Cursor cursor;
ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
Button goButtonAction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recap_page);

    goButtonAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setClickable(true);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String first_name, surname, email, phone, add_info;
            first_name = cursor.getString(0);
            surname = cursor.getString(1);
            email = cursor.getString(2);
            phone = cursor.getString(3);
            add_info = cursor.getString(4);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(first_name,surname,email,phone,add_info);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Intent arrayItems = getIntent();
    Bundle arrayItemsBundle = arrayItems.getExtras();

}
```

GarmentEntry:

```
public class GarmentEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner tcshenspinner, backprintoptionsspinner, tcbackhenspinner, cosspinner, ppspinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> tcshenspinneradapter, backprintoptionsspinneradapter, tcbackhenspinneradapter,
        cosspinneradapter, ppspinneradapter;
Button nextButton1;
public static ImageView imagePreview;
public static final String IMAGE_RES_ID_1 = "image_res_id_1";
Context contextOrder = this;
OrderDbHelper userDbHelperOrder;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseOrder;
EditText OrderNoOfShirts, OrderFrontText,OrderShirt1;
Spinner OrderColourOfShirts, OrderPrintPosition, OrderColourOfText, OrderBackPrint, OrderBackColour;
Button saveOrderDetails;
public static ArrayList<String> ORDERINFO = new ArrayList<>();
String orderinfo[];


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.garment_entry);

    final EditText shirtArray = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noofshirts);

    saveOrderDetails = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveOrderDetails);
    saveOrderDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String erm=shirtArray.getText().toString().trim();
            if (erm.length() != 0){
                ORDERINFO.add(erm);
                shirtArray.setText("");
            }
            Intent arrayItemsOrder = new Intent(GarmentEntry.this, RecapOrderDetails.class);
            Bundle arrayItemsOrderBundle = new Bundle();
        }
    });

    OrderNoOfShirts = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noofshirts);
    OrderColourOfShirts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cosspinner);
    OrderFrontText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fronttexthint);
    OrderPrintPosition = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ppspinner);
    OrderColourOfText = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.tcshenspinner);
    OrderBackPrint = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.backprintoptionsspinner);
    OrderBackColour = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.tcbackhenspinner);
    OrderShirt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nnsshirt1);

}

public void addOrder(View view){

    String no_of_shirts = OrderNoOfShirts.getText().toString();
    String colour_of_shirts = OrderColourOfShirts.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String front_text = OrderFrontText.getText().toString();
    String print_position = OrderPrintPosition.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String colour_of_text = OrderColourOfText.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String back_print = OrderBackPrint.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String back_colour = OrderBackColour.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String shirt_1 = OrderShirt1.getText().toString();

    userDbHelperOrder = new OrderDbHelper(contextOrder);
    sqLiteDatabaseOrder = userDbHelperOrder.getWritableDatabase();
    userDbHelperOrder.addInformationOrder(no_of_shirts,colour_of_shirts,front_text,print_position,colour_of_text,back_print,
            back_colour,shirt_1, null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,sqLiteDatabaseOrder);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    userDbHelperOrder.close();

}
```

RecapOrderDetails:

```
public class RecapOrderDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listViewOrder;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseOrder;
UserDbHelper userDbHelperOrder;
Cursor cursorOrder;
ListDataAdapterOrder listDataAdapterOrder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recap_order_details);

    listViewOrder = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_order);
    listViewOrder.setClickable(true);
    listDataAdapterOrder = new ListDataAdapterOrder(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.order_layout);
    listViewOrder.setAdapter(listDataAdapterOrder);
    userDbHelperOrder = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabaseOrder = userDbHelperOrder.getReadableDatabase();
    cursorOrder = userDbHelperOrder.getInformation(sqLiteDatabaseOrder);
    if (cursorOrder.moveToFirst()){
        do {

            String no_of_shirts, colour_of_shirts, front_text, print_position, text_colour, back_print, back_colour, shirt1;
            no_of_shirts = cursorOrder.getString(0);
            colour_of_shirts = cursorOrder.getString(1);
            front_text = cursorOrder.getString(2);
            print_position = cursorOrder.getString(3);
            text_colour = cursorOrder.getString(4);
            /*back_print = cursorOrder.getString(5);
            back_colour = cursorOrder.getString(6);
            shirt1 = cursorOrder.getString(7);*/
            DataProviderOrder dataProviderOrder = new DataProviderOrder(no_of_shirts,colour_of_shirts,front_text,print_position,
                    text_colour,null,null,null);
            listDataAdapterOrder.add(dataProviderOrder);

        }while (cursorOrder.moveToNext());
    }

    Intent arrayItems = getIntent();
    Bundle arrayItemsBundle = arrayItems.getExtras();
}
```

I THINK the reason why the wrong data is being passed into the second database is because of this:

```
if (cursorOrder.moveToFirst()){
        do {

            String no_of_shirts, colour_of_shirts, front_text, print_position, text_colour, back_print, back_colour, shirt1;
            no_of_shirts = cursorOrder.getString(0);
            colour_of_shirts = cursorOrder.getString(1);
            front_text = cursorOrder.getString(2);
            print_position = cursorOrder.getString(3);
            text_colour = cursorOrder.getString(4);
            /*back_print = cursorOrder.getString(5);
            back_colour = cursorOrder.getString(6);
            shirt1 = cursorOrder.getString(7);*/
            DataProviderOrder dataProviderOrder = new DataProviderOrder(no_of_shirts,colour_of_shirts,front_text,print_position,
                    text_colour,null,null,null);
            listDataAdapterOrder.add(dataProviderOrder);
```

Are the values 0-4 reserved for the first database (for DataEntryHome)?

I also think that this:

```
userDbHelperOrder = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
sqLiteDatabaseOrder = userDbHelperOrder.getReadableDatabase();
cursorOrder = userDbHelperOrder.getInformation(sqLiteDatabaseOrder);
```

has something to do with the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

On activity RecapOrderDetails, This:

```
userDbHelperOrder = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

was this issue.

To resolve it, I had to do the following:

```
OrderDbHelper = orderDbHelperOrder
```

in the main method.

And then replace

```
userDbHelperOrder = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
orderDbHelperOrder = new OrderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```